# Sorting strings based on the integer value they represent in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have an entity with a string field in it.

Sometimes this string field stores actual words, so sorting based on lexicographical order makes sense. However, there is a use case where this field stores string values like "0%", "10%", "100%", "20%".

The default string sorting generates the following sequence: 0% 10% 100% 20%.

The ideal sequence after sorting would be 0%, 10%, 20%, 100%(determined by the percentage they represent). 
It is guaranteed that there is no mixed data, i.e, you won't have "10%" and "word" appear in the same sequence that needs to be sorted.

My question is if there is a way to achieve the string sorting based on the numerical value they represent?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Search are you using? Are you using the Lucene integration or the Elasticsearch intergation?

Comment: I am using 5.11, the Lucene integration I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should alter your model to have two fields: one of integer type where you'll hold the percentage, and one of string type where you will hold the string value:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MyEntity {

  @Field
  @SortableField
  private int percentage;

  @Field
  @SortableField
  private String notPercentage;


  // ... other properties, getters and setters ...
}
```

Then when sorting you'll just sort on both fields. Since you are certain they are mutually exclusive, it's not a problem to sort on both:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = ...;
FullTextQuery ftQuery = ...;
ftQuery.sort(queryBuilder.sort().byField("percentage").andByField("notPercentage").createSort());
```

Alternatively, if you really want to keep a single String property in your ORM model (to each his own...), you can use a custom bridge to apply padding to your values, so that they are sorted correctly:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MyEntity {

  @Field(bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = PaddingIfPercentageBridge.class))
  @SortableField
  private String percentageOrNot;

  // ... other properties, getters and setters ...
}

public class PaddingIfPercentageBridge implements TwoWayStringBridge {

    private static final Pattern PERCENTAGE = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+%");

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
       if ( object == null ) {
           return null;
       }
        String string = (String) object;
       if ( !PERCENTAGE.matcher( string ).matches() ) {
           return string;
       }
        StringBuilder paddedPercentage = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int padIndex = string.length(); padIndex < 4; padIndex++ ) {
            paddedPercentage.append( '0' );
        }
        return paddedPercentage.append( string ).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object stringToObject(String stringValue) {
       // Ideally you should remove the padding here...
        return stringValue;
    }

}
```

Then you can sort on a single field:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = ...;
FullTextQuery ftQuery = ...;
ftQuery.sort(queryBuilder.sort().byField("percentageOrNot").createSort());
```